# с# чет не понятное для меня с потоками

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                Task.Run(() => {
                    dataGridView1[1, i].Value = pingSynhronyze(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString());
                });                
            }
```

`RowCount = 2`. Каким образом в `dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString()` `i=1`, и как этого избежать?

Comment: `foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvR in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                Task.Run(() => {
                    dataGridView1[1, dgvR.Index].Value = pingSynhronyze(dataGridView1[0, dgvR.Index].Value.ToString());
                });
                
            }` в принципе то же самое, но работает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Типичная ошибка с захватом переменной. Ваш таск стартует после того, как цикл закончился и переменная i уже увеличена. Попрбуйте перед захватом скопировать значение переменной и захватывать уже копию

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
{
    int j=i;
    Task.Run(() => {
        dataGridView1[1, j].Value = 
             pingSynhronyze(dataGridView1[0, j].Value.ToString());
        });                
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)