# Task/Thread в цикле не работают

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в цикле 5 методов параллельно работали(они качают картинки)

Если я делаю цикл без `Task/Thread` все прекрасно работает, но не выполняет мою задачу.
Если же я включаю в код `Task/Thread`, то цикл неведомым образом, сразу скачивает 5 элемент. P.S без тасков  все четко работает. Вопрос, почему происходить данная ситуация?

```
Task:
for(int countfilms = 0; countfilms < 5; countfilms++)
{
      await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
      {
          string namefilm = Regex.Replace(document.QuerySelectorAll("div.sect-cont.sect-items.clearfix div.th-title")[countfilms].TextContent, @"\s+", " ");
          string link = await Bing.CheckAndSend(namefilm, new ImageElement());
          TakePicture(DownloadPicture(in link, in countfilms));
      });
}
```

```
Thread:
for(int countfilms = 0; countfilms < 5; countfilms++) 
{
     new Thread(async() =>
     {
        string namefilm = Regex.Replace(document.QuerySelectorAll("div.sect-cont.sect-items.clearfix div.th-title")[countfilms].TextContent, @"\s+", " ");
        string link = await Bing.CheckAndSend(namefilm, new ImageElement());
        TakePicture(DownloadPicture(in link, in countfilms));
     }).Start();
}
```

`TakePicture`- Ивент(Делегат)

Comment: Task != Thread. Зачем вы вообще тут создаете потоки? `Task:` - я надеюсь это у вас не в коде? `Regex.Replace` - уверены? Ну а ответ, скорей всего [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/220553).

Comment: Нет таск не в когде. Потоки нужны для того, чтобы если попалась большая картинка, она не задерживала маленькие, пока она скачиваться будет

Comment: Ну так эту же задачу решают и Task, в том кол-ве потоков, сколько им надо.

Comment: Да я знаю что таском. Мне подсказали, раз  с таском не работает, попробуй треад. Ваш ответ помог, все работает, спасибо

Comment: Странный у вас там советчик... Если не работает одно, значит надо это бросать и переходить сразу на другое? Такое себе решение... Не работает - значит делаете что-то не так. Потоки вас только замедлят, вот и вся суть)

Comment: Если мой ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его. Если же нет, то давайте я его удалю, чтобы он не мешался.

Comment: @aepot вам тоже спасибо, я таск фактори писал, т.к читал старую,  либо плохую статью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо никаких Task.Factory...и старайтесь не выполнять одну и ту же операцию в цикле, когда ее выполнить можно 1 раз.

Нужно например выполнить много запросов, но чтобы одновременно были активны только 5.

```cs
var nodes = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.sect-cont.sect-items.clearfix div.th-title");
using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    int id = i; // это исправляет проблему захвата счетчика цикла, чтобы не было 5 5 5 5 5
    tasks.Add(((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            string namefilm = Regex.Replace(nodes[id].TextContent, @"\s+", " ");
            string link = await Bing.CheckAndSend(namefilm, new ImageElement());
            TakePicture(DownloadPicture(in link, in id)); // здесь сомнение, почему эти методы синхронные? Они очень быстро отрабатывают?
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }))());
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). При использовании асинхронного программирования про существование `Thread` лучше забыть.

Comment: Кхм, вопрос не про то как правильно ведь, а почему стартует с 5-го элемента, а это, дубликат (ссылка в первом комментарии)... Также человек хочет не "5 первых", а "по 5", судя по коду там запросы в поисковик идут, а он может сотню запросов заблокировать, нужен семафор (что вроде тоже было, даже у Вас и можно было бы закрыть дублем, если думать в этом ключе).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, дописал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я с телефона, завтра дубли поищу, если автор ответ не примет.

Comment: На конкретно поставленный вопрос "почему с 5-го" ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/220553), автор сказал "спасибо, ответ помог".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я видел, да. То что у него где-то заработало, это не значит что он написал тоже самое, что и я.

Comment: Я Вам изначально сказал, что не пойму, к чему этот ответ, ибо он не отвечает на поставленное "почему с 5-го", прям цитирую "почему происходить данная ситуация?". Этот ответ из разряда "Я вам не скажу, почему конкретно у вас проблема, но смотрите как можно". Даже если человеку это поможет, он примет ответ (ибо захочет отблагодарить), это не отменит тот факт, что на поставленный вопрос, самого ответа нету. Вот человек написал код, у него внутри цикла `Task`, он замечает, что `i` у него имеет не то значение, которое он ожидает, гуглит, находит этот вопрос, читает ваш ответ, получает нужное? Нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в цикле 5 методов параллельно работали` - сделано. Я понял, о чем вы. Просто дал автору кусок, на мой взгляд, хорошего кода. Если вы против, то мы уже обсуждали эту тему. Нажмите стрелочку вниз.

Comment: Ну, если читать все вопросы сквозь пальцы, вычитывая там только то, что конкретно Вы хотите видеть, то как бы... о чем спорить тогда? Я как видите, уже давно перестал тут следить за порядком, ибо само сообщество не хочет порядка. Ваше право, хотите оставлять явный дубликат открытым, оставляйте. Мое мнение выше я думаю, Вы поняли.

Comment: А должен он быть асинхронным  TakePicture? Он быстро отрабатывает, зачем ему вообще `async` если он в таске?

Comment: @Houl все зависит от того, что там внутри. Если там работа с сетью, то надо делать асинхронным. И таск не равно поток https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250886/373567 - почитайте.